# Mobile Hybrid App: Working in browser like chrome,IE etc. But not working any mobile device

Tags: iphone, xcode, devexpress, hybrid-mobile-app, phonejs

I have created a simple project with PhoneJS. i can see output simple project in google chorme and ie etc. i have added this project into xcode 5 use making UIWebview. Builded and install app to iphone 5. i cant see output simple project in any mobile device like iphone 5s and sumsung s4 etc. 
index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Making Change Happen</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" /> 
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/dx.common.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/dx.ios.default.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/dx.android.holo-dark.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/dx.tizen.black.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/dx.generic.light.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/dx.win8.black.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/globalize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/dx.phonejs.js"></script>

        <link rel="dx-template" type="text/html" href="lib/layouts/SlideOut/SlideOutLayout.html" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/layouts/SlideOut/SlideOutLayout.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/layouts/SlideOut/SlideOutLayout.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

        <!-- Views -->
        <link  rel="dx-template" type="text/html" href="views/news/news.html"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="views/news/news.js"></script>

        <link  rel="dx-template" type="text/html" href="views/About PES/aboutpes.html"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="views/About PES/aboutpes.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js file

```
window.AppNamespace = {};
$(function () {
    AppNamespace.app = new DevExpress.framework.html.HtmlApplication({
        namespace: AppNamespace,
        navigationType: 'slideout',
        navigation: [
        {
            title: "News",
            action: "#news",
        },
        {
            title: "About PES",
            action: "#aboutpes"
        }]
    });
    AppNamespace.app.router.register(":view/:id", { view: "news", id: undefined });
    AppNamespace.app.navigate();


});
```

Comment: I hope this blog can help you: http://formattc.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/ios-web-inspector/

Answer (score 0):

Try to build package using Visual Studio with DevExtreme installed.
It allows to build native packages for all supported platforms (ios, android, windows phone).

Check out following link 
http://help.devexpress.com/DevExtreme/Documentation/Howto/Packaging

If package will be built ok with DevExtreme, then your app is ok, and the problem with the way you do packaging. Will be glad to help you, just try and report the results.